# Асинхронное чтение/запись в процесс C# .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, асинхронность, процесс, .net-framework

Реализую функционал асинхронных операций чтения/записи в процесс. Однако, команды, переданные процессу, не выполняются.

Создание процесса и редирект необходимых потоков:

```
StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder outputError = new StringBuilder();
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    ErrorDialog = false,
    Arguments = "/cpython.exe"
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;

AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => 
{
    if (e.Data == null) { outputWaitHandle.Set();}
    else{ outputText.AppendLine(e.Data); }
}

process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => 
{
    if (e.Data == null) { errorWaitHandle.Set();}
    else{ outputError.AppendLine(e.Data); }
}

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

if (timeout > 0)
{
    if (process.WaitForExit(timeout) &&
        outputWaitHandle(timeout) && 
        errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout))
    {
        // Do some work...
    }
}
```

Асинхронная запись в поток:

```
if (process.StandardInput.BaseStream.CanWrite)
{
    byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("print 'Hello'");
    IAsyncResult handle = process.StandardInput.BaseStream.BeginWrite(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length, EndWriteCallBack, process.StandardInput.BaseStream);

    if (handle.IsCompleted)
    {
        // Do smth ....
    }
    else
    {
         handle.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
}

//Callback func
void EndWriteCallBack(IAsyncResult handle)
{
    process.StandardInput.BaseStream.EndWrite(handle);
}
```

На выходе ожидаю, что мой асинхронный вывод вернёт мне напечатанную строку:

```
outputText = "print 'Hello'"
```

как это бы сделала консоль. Однако, output всегда пуст. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

**P.S.:** если убрать редирект входного потока, всё прекрасно работает. Но хочется, чтобы в одну и ту же консоль можно было слать несколько команд, как это можно делать, работая с нею напрямую.

Comment: Зачем вы асинхронно пишите в поток - и сразу же ждете окончания записи?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, асинхронно пишу, потому что выбора нет. Согласно документации, если я всё правильно понял, нельзя комбинировать синхронные и асинхронные операции, а так как output у меня асинхронный, писать нужно тоже асинхронно. Сразу же жду - потому что не предполагается длительного ввода.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на свой вопрос здесь (спасибо автору за это, **++++** к карме!):
[Асинхронный ввод/вывод в консоль, полностью интерактивная программа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26260573/3844702)

Поправив немного код (дописал метод, реализующий делегат + комментарии), получил вот что:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class СmdShell
{
    private Process shellProcess;

    //Делегат
    public delegate void onDataHandler(СmdShell sender, string e);
    //Событие "получение новых данных"
    public event onDataHandler onData;

    public СmdShell()
    {
        try
        {
            shellProcess = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");

            //Если хотите оставить консоль живой после посланной вами команды
            //Можно ещё передать "/c" - выполнится команда с последующим завершением
            //Либо вообще ничего не передавать
            //Оставлю ссылку после кода на то, какие ещё входные параметры можно задать консоли
            si.Arguments = "/k";

            //Перенаправление всех потоков, чтобы можно было асинхронное читать выходные потоки
            //и писать во входной поток
            si.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            si.RedirectStandardError = true;

            //Обязательно "false", иначе редиректы не будут работать
            si.UseShellExecute = false;

            //Чтобы не создавались лишние окошки консоли
            si.CreateNoWindow = true;

            //Знать, из какой директории запускаться
            si.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR");

            //Сообщаем процессу стартовую информацию
            shellProcess.StartInfo = si;

            //События обработки из потоков вывода
            shellProcess.OutputDataReceived += shellProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            shellProcess.ErrorDataReceived += shellProcess_ErrorDataReceived;

            //Стартуем процесс
            shellProcess.Start();

            //Начинаем читать выходные потоки
            shellProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
            shellProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void shellProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        doOnData(e.Data);
    }

    void shellProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        doOnData(e.Data);
    }

    private void doOnData(string data)
    {
        if (onData != null) onData(this, data);
    }

    public void write(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            shellProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void test_onData(СmdShell sender, string e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Тестовая прога:

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CmdShell test = new CmdShell();
        test.onData += test.test_onData;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter command:");
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            test.write(command);
        }
    }
}
```

**Внимание, ПРОБЛЕМА!**

Если передавать в качестве команды "python.exe" всё ещё не возвращается output. Но, если передать заведомо невалидную команду, вернётся ошибка, отданная питоном.

**ВОПРОС!**
Как же всё таки получить весь output Питона???

P.S.: ссылка на аргументы для запуска cmd.exe:
[CMD - запуск новой копии интерпретатора команд Windows](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/cmd.html)